# ASP.NET MapPath to the root of the Solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, path

I'm having trouble selecting the root of the solution in my ASP.NET Application.
I have three applications inside this solution, a Web app, an API and an app for Reports. I was trying to select my Reports app from the Web app in code using Server.MapPath but I can't get to the folder.

I tried Server.MapPath("\Tagus.TMS.Reports/Media/VoyageControlReport.rpt") from inside the web app.

How can I get that app path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Server.MapPath will use the "application level of IIS" to determine the path returned.

So the path returned is the physcial location of the root of the application (web site) + what ever parameter you pushed into the "MapPath" method.

I would advise you to make a "/Data" directory in your website and use the "Server.MapPath("/Data/dataFileToLoad.rpt") to get the physcial path.

It also gives you a nice isolation for your data files (rpt) versus your runtime files (dll's).

Hope this helps,

Comment: It's an interesting solution but my project leader wants us to keep using things as they are and get the path this way.
all the app folders are inside a folder called "src".
So it's like src\Tagus.TMS.Web  src\Tagus.TMS.Reports  src\Tagus.TMS.API

Comment: Then why not create a VDir (/data) pointing to the deployment location of the other project.  

In all honesty, i think that 'source structure' != 'deployment structure' and anyone forcing this is not seeying the problems its creating. Runtime isolation is good, low-cost maintenance is good (COO), mixing goals usually ends in tears.  
Bottom line, when deploying the "API" will have to be deployed into the GAC or the BIN directory of the website to be available anyway. Seems like you're already deploying mixed.

Comment: The issue here is that there is NO link between the website and the reports project except for the fact its in 1 solution in visual studio. If you 'assume' the location of the report project relative to the website, but not a child/vdir-reference of, its considered 'brittle'. The opted VDir solution makes this reference also clean in runtime.

Comment: I'll try to do my best in getting him to accept this solution, which seems better than what we have already. Thanks for the help

Comment: Feel free to ask more questions for argumentation or send me an inboard message.

Comment: I can't even get the server object resolved.  When I put Server.MapPath, R# doesn't even recognize the type and suggests no using statements to throw in for it.  I guess it's in System.Web but I added that and no luck.  I'm outside my mvc webapp so I don't even think I can use Server.MapPath to get the root path of my web app anyway