# Cannot read OWL file from the root of the web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, owl, ontology, dotnetrdf

I have a website that uses an ontology as data source.
I already read the file from a local drive,like c:\test.owl, and it works well but since I want to publish the website, I need to change the path of the owl file to a place that can get access in a deployed website; when I copy the owl file to App_data folder or to the main root of the website, then I have a run time error on "cannot read RDF from the file 'full path of file' since it does not exist."

I am using c#.net and in order to read the owl file, I use dotNetRDF library.
Here is the code:

```
using VDS.RDF;
public void GetGraph()
{
 string fileUri = @"~\App_Data\FinalRecSysOntology.owl";
    // create a graph to load the owl file into it---------------
     IGraph g = new Graph();
    //load the OWL file------------------          
    g.LoadFromFile(fileUri);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for my question;
`Server.MapPath` helps in these cases. For any physical file this solution can help to be able to read the file from the web application itself after deployment. This question - [ASP.NET MapPath to the root of the Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002514/asp-net-mappath-to-the-root-of-the-solution) - helped me.

Here is the code;

```
 public string GetFileURI()
{
    string fileURI = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Data/FinalRecSysOntology.owl");
    return fileURI;
}
```